# Will uninstalling Git delete my local repositories?

Tags: git, git-bash

I have been having some problems with Git Bash on my computer. I've been trying to package and distribute a repository, however some of the commands don't run properly on Git Bash. However, they do work on other Command Line Interfaces, so I have a feeling that this is an issue with the Git Bash installation on my computer.

Likely unsurprisingly, I have a lot of Git repositories on my computer. My ideal plan would be to uninstall and reinstall Git and, assuming that the local repositories remain, continue from where I left off. If the assumption is not met, most of the local repositories are up-to-date with the remote repositories, so it wouldn't be overly difficult to initialize a repository locally and to pull the current commit of each repository to each local repository. However, considering the number of repositories I have, it would be a bit time-consuming.

I tried searching on the Internet as well as on Stack Overflow, but I have not found any answer (or question, for that matter) about whether uninstalling Git deletes my remote repositories or renders them useless. I have a feeling that this would not happen, but I wanted to be sure this is the case.

Comment: So why do you think uninstalling Git deletes your repositories? They're stored separately where you specified.

Comment: Why do you think uninstalling and reinstalling git for windows will change anything? “some of the commands don't run properly” Then that, it seems to me, is what you should be asking about.

Comment: @iBug I understand that the information for each repository is stored in a *.git* directory in the repository. However, I am unsure if there are any configuration files or files of similar sort which would render the local repository unusable.

Comment: Without git, the repository _will_ be unusable qua repository. But no files will be harmed.

Comment: @matt I am working out the issue with commands with a developer from PyPA. Since he was unable to replicate the issue on his machine, I was going to uninstall/reinstall Git from my computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally uninstalling applications won't delete the files you produce.

This should be a safe operation.

What's somewhat problematic though is that it sounds like losing these would be a problem to you, implying you are not making backups. Might be a good day to start. It's easier to trust backups than some stranger on the internet telling you it's safe to delete it =)